# Remove columns that have one zero value

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

I have data frame like this

```
       class     col2    col3   col4   col5  col6
A      AA         0        5      4      2    15
B      AA         4       10     14     12    25
C      AA         19       2      8      5     3  
D      SS         17       5      5     32    12
E      AA         14       2      12    14    55
F      II         12      17       1     9     0 
G      SS         10      37       8     2    17
H      II         17       7       5     7   14
```

I want to remove all columns that have zero values

```
       class         col3    col4   col5     
A      AA              5       4      2   
B      AA               10     14     12    
C      AA                2      8      5      
D      SS                5      5     32    
E      AA                2     12    14    
F      II               17       1     9      
G      SS               37       8     2    
H      II                7       5     7
```

So the result I want is just want those columns which do not contain any zeros

Thank you

Comment: `df[,colSums(df==0)==0]`.

Comment: @user2974951 you have answered the question that was asked nicely! But actually all the columns have zeroes and the OP wants to know how to remove the rows that don't have any zeroes, rather than the columns. So it should be `df[rowSums(df==0)==0,]`.

Comment: why is col3 remaining?

Comment: I edited the question, can you please check it again

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description I assume you want to remove *rows* with zero values, not *columns*. Here's how you can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df, across(everything(), ~.!=0))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   class  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 AA        4    10    14    12    25
#> 2 AA       19     2     8     5     3
#> 3 AA       14     2    12    14    55
#> 4 SS       10    37     8     2    17
```

Comment: I'm sorry i have modified the question can you please check it again

Answer (score 4):

With the new dataset:
base R:
In base R we can use `Filter` and negate `any`:

```
Filter(function(x) !any(x %in% 0), df)
```

```
  class col3 col4 col5
A    AA    5    4    2
B    AA   10   14   12
C    AA    2    8    5
D    SS    5    5   32
E    AA    2   12   14
F    II   17    1    9
G    SS   37    8    2
H    II    7    5    7
```

Comment: I'm sorry i have modified the question can you please check it again

Comment: See my update, please.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution:

```r
df[apply(df == 0, 2, sum) == 0]

#>   class col3 col4 col5
#> A    AA    5    4    2
#> B    AA   10   14   12
#> C    AA    2    8    5
#> D    SS    5    5   32
#> E    AA    2   12   14
#> F    II   17    1    9
#> G    SS   37    8    2
#> H    II    7    5    7
```

Comment: Please note rownames

Comment: Thanks for having commented my answer, @patL. I had no rownames in my dataframe, but I have meanwhile added them.

Comment: It was just to match the op ;) thanks

Answer (score 3):

One `base` R option could be:

```r
df_so[,!sapply(df_so, function(x) any(x == 0))]

#  class col3 col4 col5
#A    AA    5    4    2
#B    AA   10   14   12
#C    AA    2    8    5
#D    SS    5    5   32
#E    AA    2   12   14
#F    II   17    1    9
#G    SS   37    8    2
#H    II    7    5    7
```

---

**Not my answer**, but @user2974951 provided a very fast and straightforward answer as a comment in the Original Post:

```r
df[,colSums(df==0)==0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using a combination of `select` and `where`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(where(~!any(. == 0)))
```

**Output**

```
  class col3 col4 col5
A    AA    5    4    2
B    AA   10   14   12
C    AA    2    8    5
D    SS    5    5   32
E    AA    2   12   14
F    II   17    1    9
G    SS   37    8    2
H    II    7    5    7
```

Before `select_if` was deprecated, we could have written it like:

```
df %>%
  select_if( ~ !any(. == 0))
```

**Data Table**

Here is a possible `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, .SD,  .SDcols = !names(dt)[(colSums(dt == 0) > 0)]]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(class = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "SS", "AA", "II", 
"SS", "II"), col2 = c(0L, 4L, 19L, 17L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 17L), 
    col3 = c(5L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 17L, 37L, 7L), col4 = c(4L, 
    14L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 5L), col5 = c(2L, 12L, 5L, 32L, 
    14L, 9L, 2L, 7L), col6 = c(15L, 25L, 3L, 12L, 55L, 0L, 17L, 
    14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the trick `Filter` + `anyNA`

```
> Filter(Negate(anyNA), replace(df, df == 0, NA))
  class col3 col4 col5
A    AA    5    4    2
B    AA   10   14   12
C    AA    2    8    5
D    SS    5    5   32
E    AA    2   12   14
F    II   17    1    9
G    SS   37    8    2
H    II    7    5    7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove columns that have at least one zero value, u can uses colSums(df == 0) == 0 to identify columns where the sum of zeros is zero (i.e., no zeros in the column). The resulting df will only contain columns without any zero values.

```
df <- data.frame(
  row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
  class = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "SS", "AA", "II", "SS", "II"),
  col2 = c(0, 4, 19, 17, 14, 12, 10, 17),
  col3 = c(5, 10, 2, 5, 2, 17, 37, 7),
  col4 = c(4, 14, 8, 5, 12, 1, 8, 5),
  col5 = c(2, 12, 5, 32, 14, 9, 2, 7),
  col6 = c(15, 25, 3, 12, 55, 0, 17, 14)
)

df[, colSums(df == 0) == 0, drop = FALSE]
class col3 col4 col5
A    AA    5    4    2
B    AA   10   14   12
C    AA    2    8    5
D    SS    5    5   32
E    AA    2   12   14
F    II   17    1    9
G    SS   37    8    2
H    II    7    5    7
```

or simply

```
df[, !apply(df == 0, 2, any)]
```

or

```
df[, colSums(df != 0) == nrow(df)]
```

U can also use purr package aswell

```
library(purrr)
df %>% keep(~ !any(. == 0)) # or discard
```